# Error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: hibernate, hql

This is my SQL query

`select * from customer where cust_acnt_nbr IN
    (select cust_acnt_nbr from Asset where dstrct_id IN
        (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = 'ATLANTA'))`

I converted this SQL to HQL

```
    final Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from customer where cust_acnt_nbr in (select cust_acnt_nbr from Asset where dstrct_id in (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = :name))");
    query.setParameter("name", districtName);
```

This give an error :

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: customer is not mapped [from customer where cust_acnt_nbr in (select cust_acnt_nbr from com.ironmountain.model.Asset where dstrct_id in (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = :name))]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a closer look here: `customer is not mapped`, i think it will be clear. The problem is that Hibernate can't find the `customer` entity. Java classes and properties are case sensitive in HQL, maybe `customer` is meant to be `Customer`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem , hibernate is case sensitive.
this query was my query :
Query query = session.createQuery(" select e from student e where e.id=:id");

and i changed student to Student, 
this query is correct :
Query query = session.createQuery(" select e from Student e where e.id=:id");